# My Pyttsx3 module is not saying anything Text to speech fucntion is not working not getting any audio output

Tags: python-3.x, module, pycharm, speech-recognition

I have **intsalle**d **pyttsx3 2.7v** and **python 3.7v** in **pycharm**

> My code : Speak funtion is not returning audio output

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init("dummy")
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

def speak(text):
    print('Rex:' + text)
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

print("On")
speak("This programe is runniing perfectly")
print("End")
```

> Output

```
On
Rex:This programe is runniing perfectly
End

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy, I have worked with Pyttsx3. Try the below program.

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')           # <--- sapi 5 is for Windows
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)  # <--- voice id can be male(0) or female(1) 


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

There is no need for print statements.